# multipart/form-data losing bytes on large files

Tags: c++, multipartform-data, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am writing a `multipart/form-data` parser in C++, since the available options seem very scarce.

My initial approach was to use `istream::getline` to buffer one line (or partial line) at a time so I could detect boundaries. However, while this worked for smaller files, it did not work for larger files. With large (>50MB) files, the bad bit of `cin` would occasionally get set, and after clearing the istream, I noticed I would lose bytes. I have no idea why, and that is the purpose of this question.

However, if I increase the buffer size to 4MB and use `istream::read` to dump the entire `multipart/form-data` request to a file, I don't lose any bytes and `cin` never gets bad bit set. I can then reopen the dumped file as an `ifstream` instead of using `cin` and my original small buffer `getline` approach works perfectly.

Any insight as to what's happening here? Could it be some side effect of FastCGI or Lighttpd?

Edit:

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
#include <fcgio.h>
//...

int main()
{
    //...
    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

    const size_t LEN = 1024;
    vector<char> v(LEN); // Workaround for getting duplicates of every byte?
    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0) {
        fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in, &v[0], v.size());
        //... (eventually calls _parseMultipartFormFieldFile)
    }

    //...
}

/*
    Extract a file from a multipart form section

    istream should already have boundary and headers removed up throguh the final "\r\n"

    Note that there are a lot of potential off-by-one errors here. Need to pay special attention
    to gcount() and what is present in the buffer in each given scenario. Hence why you see:

    gcount
    gcount-1
    gcount-2

    These offsets are due to null terminator sometimes being appended, sometimes not, and/or '\r' being present or not.

    It is possible for a few rare things to happen that will break this function:

    1. Malicious content length

    Client could lie about content length and send much more than we have room for. Should count bytes eventually, but easy enough to configure webserver to protect us.
*/
bool _parseMultipartFormFieldFile(
    Request & req,
    istream & input,
    const string & name,
    const string & upload_dir,
    const string & boundary,
    const string & end_boundary
)
{
    static unsigned int file_id = 0; //used to generate unique file names

    //Need fixed buffer size to prevent running out of RAM (malicious or not)
    char buf[4096];

    string file_name = upload_dir + ECPP_TMP_FILE + to_string(file_id++);

    ofstream f(file_name, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);
    if (!f.is_open())
        return false;

    bool eof = false;
    while (!eof) {
        //Out of space in flash?
        if (!f.good())
            return false;

        f.flush();

        input.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
        unsigned int gcount = input.gcount();

        if (input.bad()) {
            //Crap! If we're here, we have most likely lost a few bytes...
            input.clear();
            continue;
        }
        else if (input.eof()) {
            //If we are here, the multipart/form-data request was malformed
            f.close();
            remove(file_name.c_str()); //Delete malformed file
            return false;
        }
        else if (input.fail()) {
            //If we are in this condition, it means we encountered a line longer than our buffer
            //There is no null terminator in this case, so write out what we have
            f.write(buf, gcount);
            input.clear(); //clear fail flag
            continue;
        }

        if (gcount >= 2 && buf[gcount-2] == '\r') {
            string peek = peekLine(input); //uses putback - modifies gcount()
            if (peek == boundary || peek == end_boundary) {
                //If we are in here, it means we encountered the last line in the section
                //That means there is a trailing '\r' which we need to remove in addition to the null terminator
                f.write(buf, gcount-2); // Remove null terminator and \r before writing
                req.file[name] = file_name;
                eof = true;
                continue;
            }
        }

        //If we are here it means we read in the entire line.
        //Write out everything (minus the null terminator), and also add in the newline that was stripped by getline()
        f.write(buf, gcount-1);
        f.write("\n", 1);
    }

    return true;
}
```

So, in short, the problem is that if I pass `cin_fcgi_streambuf` to `_parseMultipartFormFieldFile`, I lose bytes (bad bit gets triggered), but if I instead indiscriminately dump `cin_fcgi_streambuf` to a file with a `char buf[4000000]` + `input.read()`, and then pass an `ifstream` of that file to `_parseMultipartFormFieldFile`, then it works fine.

Comment: Show your code. 50MB is not really large on a modern system, so I do not think you have a size related issue. badbit is generally not recoverable, so resetting it is not safe unless you can deal with possible lost reads.

Comment: Did you use a library to handle the FastCGI protocol or only your own code?

Comment: @FireLancer I used the "official" FastCGI libraries from the (now defunct) fastcgi.com (I put a copy of it in GitHub: https://github.com/RPGillespie6/FastCGI)

Comment: @FireLancer I updated with (hopefully) the relevant code. I can give even more context, if you think it would be helpful, but it would just make the question a huge wall of code.

Comment: @Gillespie did you check the ```fcgiapp.c``` line num aprx. 2215
```reqDataPtr->in = NewReader(reqDataPtr, 8192, 0);```
So I think you've to allocate your buffer size max 8192

Answer (score 0):

Main fact `input.getline` will return without `CRLF`.
So if you post a `binary` file, what will happen ?
Otherwise, your example `source code` does not manage `multiple posted file request`.
Case, you just opened one file stream. That's why you have to change your source code pattern.

You can upload unlimited size of `data|file`. Try this solution

```
const char* ctype = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfm9qwXVLSbFKKR88";
size_t content_length = 1459606;
http_payload* hp = new http_payload(ctype, content_length);
if (hp->is_multipart()) {
    int ret = hp->read_all("C:\\temp\\");
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << hp->get_last_error() << std::endl;
        hp->clear();
    }
    else {
        std::string dir_str("C:\\upload_dir\\");
        ret = hp->read_files([&dir_str](http_posted_file* file) {
            std::string path(dir_str.c_str());
            path.append(file->get_file_name());
            file->save_as(path.c_str());
            file->clear(); path.clear();
            std::string().swap(path);
        });
        hp->clear();
        std::cout << "Total file uploaded :" << ret << std::endl;
    }
}
else {
    int ret = hp->read_all();
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << hp->get_last_error() << std::endl;
        hp->clear();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Posted data :" << hp->get_body() << std::endl;
        hp->clear();

    }
}
```

https://github.com/safeonlineworld/web_jsx/blob/0d08773c95f4ae8a9799dbd29e0a4cd84413d108/src/web_jsx/core/http_payload.cpp#L402

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 did you check the git source code ?

Comment: No, but even if the answer were there, your answer is supposed to be here on the site

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Here I want to explain how to read posted file (```multipart/form-data```) from ```istream``` without losing data. But you say that, this isn't address the question. How ? Please explain me...

Comment: It does not tell the OP what is wrong with their approach or how to directly fix it. A completely alternative solution is a blunt instrument here, particularly as we have yet to rule out external factors.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Main fact ```input.getline``` will return without ```CRLF```. So if you post a binary file, what will happen ?
Otherwise, this example source code does not manage multiple posted file request.
Case, he just opened one file stream. That's why he have to change his source code pattern.

Comment: Sounds like that would make a good answer! Fancy posting it as such? It's no use telling me in a comment...